# MultiCore Shared Memory Atomic Operations

Tags: arm, esp32, freertos

Would it be necessary to use a mutex for atomic operations on shared memory, in a multicore environment, where one CPU is only ever reading and the other CPU is only ever writing? I am guessing that this may depend on architecture, so if an example is needed then ARM (Cortex) and/or ESP32?

I already know that a mutex is not needed for atomic operations in a single-core environment where one thread is only ever reading and the other thread only ever writing (https://www.freertos.org/FreeRTOS_Support_Forum_Archive/May_2019/freertos_Shared_variable_between_a_write_thred_and_a_read_thread_a0408decbaj.html).

Comment: There are references in the ARM TRM (technical reference manual).  You need the writes/reads to be atomic (ie, take place in a single cycle and have controlled BUS use arriving in order).  For example an Ardino is an 8bit CPU, so writes of `int` will take four cycles.  This is not atomic and you will see partial updates.  So generally, you can use 32bit or even 64bit atomics on ARM systems.  This is probably not globally true for every ARM, but  for an OS or specific system (embedded) you could rely on this.  Er the systems  where it is not true are not multi-core, afaik.

Answer (score 0):

One solution that has been around for decades (I already used this 30 years ago) is the concept of mailboxes.

Simplest mailbox is just a structure or buffer with a flag. This flag should be of the minimum size that can be accessed in an atomic operation from both processors sharing the memory. It should also be located at a memory address that both processors see as "aligned" to ensure single-cycle read/write accesses, e.g. 32 bit word boundaries in the case of 32 bit ARM processors. This might be tricky to implement in non- RISC-alike architectures.

The flag usage is very simple. The processor that writes the data waits for the flag to be signalled as "buffer empty", maybe a simple null value, then write the data to the mailbox's buffer and signal "buffer not empty" by setting a magic number into the flag, maybe a non- null value.

The processor receiving the data just has to wait for the flag to be signalled as "buffer not empty" before reading the data, and setting the flag back to "buffer empty".

Whether you have primitives supporting this mechanism without relying in a constant flag polling, or not, is tightly dependent on your hardware and operating system.

I've used this mechanism in heterogeneous architectures (processor + co-processor of different architectures/capabilities running different applications), but homogeneous multicore processors are well supported by many RTOSes today, including freeRTOS, and other mechanisms as queues and semaphores/mutexes are probably more appropriated for the synchronization part. Some current SoC's support hardware semaphores and memory-access interrupts that can improve performance greatly.

**EDIT:**
There is one freeRTOS feature that can assist you here, message buffers. There is one example using ST's STM32H745 dual-core SoC [[here](https://www.freertos.org/STM32H7_Dual_Core_AMP_RTOS_demo.html)] that comes with a companion article [[here](https://www.freertos.org/2020/02/simple-multicore-core-to-core-communication-using-freertos-message-buffers.html)] written by freeRTOS's [Richard Barry](https://www.freertos.org/author/ribarry.html).